# After changing innerHTML, page automatically reloads?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a simple JavaScript/HTML page that inserts an audio player after being given a URL. Every time I press the button that the code below generates, the audio player is inserted, and then the page seems to refresh, getting rid of that HTML.

HTML:

```
<div id="titleBlock">
    <h4>Livestream Listener</h4>
    <p>Enter a livestream URL below so you can listen in-browser.</p>
    <form>
        <input id="stream" type="url">
        <button onclick="livestreamlisten()" class="btn">Listen</button>
    </form>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="streamBlock">
</div>
```

JS:

```
function getStreamURL(){
    var stream = document.getElementById('stream').value;
    return stream;
}

function insertPlayer(url){
    var html = `
        <audio controls>
            <source src="${url}" type="audio/mpeg">
            <source src="${url}" type="audio/ogg">
        </audio>
    `;
    document.getElementById("streamBlock").innerHTML = html;
}

function livestreamlisten(){
    var url = getStreamURL();
    insertPlayer(url);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the button be a simple button, not a "submit" button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="livestreamlisten()" class="btn">Listen</button>
```

Alternatively you could just get rid of the surrounding `<form>`.

Answer (score 0):

Either do what @Pointy suggested, or pass the event object to your `livestreamlisten(event)` function and call `event.preventDefault()` inside it like so:

```js
function getStreamURL(){
    var stream = document.getElementById('stream').value;
    return stream;
}

function insertPlayer(url){
    var html = `
        <audio controls>
            <source src="${url}" type="audio/mpeg">
            <source src="${url}" type="audio/ogg">
        </audio>
    `;
    document.getElementById("streamBlock").innerHTML = html;
}

function livestreamlisten(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default behavior of "reloading"
    var url = getStreamURL();
    insertPlayer(url);
}
```

```html
<div id="titleBlock">
    <h4>Livestream Listener</h4>
    <p>Enter a livestream URL below so you can listen in-browser.</p>
    <form>
        <input id="stream" type="url">
        <button onclick="livestreamlisten(event)" class="btn">Listen</button>
    </form>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="streamBlock">
</div>
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `return false;` to the `livestreamlisten()` function, to prevent the button from doing it's default action. Without it, you will get side-effects like form submissions, etc. This also applies to anchor tags `<a>`, e.g., links that should fire a function on click.

The method becomes:

```
function livestreamlisten(){
    var url = getStreamURL();
    insertPlayer(url);
    return false;
}
```